# CSS font family not working For IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with an `IE11` browser only below code snippet applied and its working for `Chrome` and `Firefox` but the same font not working in `IE11`.

```
.auction-bid span, .ending-soon, .auction-ending-soon, .upcoming, .mfxr-logo b, a.divider, .btn-purple, .btn-purple-small-font, .btn-white, .btn-green, .btn-dark-grey, .btn-dark, .btn-green-tko, .btn-green-tko:hover, .signed-up.btn-green-tko, .offer_title h2.thin-purple-title, .rewards-offer p b, .reward-progress-amount, .offer-title, .offer-title-entry-tier, .offer-window, .green-ribbon-text, .acct-points-block span.acct-points, .offer_signup, .offer-item-level, .redeem-now, .redeem-now-internal a, .offer_signup_bundle, .offer-detail-message-block p.offer-message-title, .hero-content-entry-tier-benefits p.hero-title-entry-tier-benefits span, .survey-thank-you, .reward-redemption-tabs li a, .survey-thank-you {
    font-family: "UniversLTW01-67BoldCn",sans-serif;
```

### }

@font-face{
font-family:"UniversLTW10-67BoldCn";
src:url("/dv2/2/de8453e9-b2a6-4554-bf75-5f0ff5a2e236.eot?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&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5#iefix");
src:url("/dv2/2/de8453e9-b2a6-4554-bf75-5f0ff5a2e236.eot?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&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5#iefix") format("eot"),url("/dv2/14/edd7b84c-1937-4bbd-a9cd-e19c35f19b6b.woff2?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&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5") format("woff2"),url("/dv2/3/e6c2f397-706a-4224-9c0a-069effd9da88.woff?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&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5") format("woff"),url("/dv2/1/528d0fca-b028-48b5-8003-f010575e8949.ttf?d44f19a684109620e484167fa390e818aaaef8109cdd42fe911f1f1944c6f755a6c53f937307a632adec70e34a75cd22651a8e1008fa43d859bf3de6be050b80b709b7a19da8b96167c1578bb3b05eadc5fd0e350ff478daa9c402204f281d80cfc0935138fc83c0e8eeb68a5a2267682e568bae5815045f54673e724b6599de16c3819b621efebae255a555e88ef744058b5c37c26ff2e0f1bd4a0dad36945fa7b5ba0f9cf71479f8c9ec8db5688ff4a22b78ba2206f1d5076f240b98d5d23d7395b1b09565b1cdbe3ab7add707b6728c91aa5375a6fad9fbb044dc9a5bb0d34ebeeaa5a612e4611e976dcb04dfc0715a9d11fdd0c87dd59fe2f2f28065b72267bfd2d2e3b041ce&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5") format("truetype"),url("/dv2/11/c52f6cb2-23c6-46b1-b6c5-e0a1da3e577c.svg?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&projectId=a8cd6cbf-61a3-40a6-bb81-11a6b6b11eb5#c52f6cb2-23c6-46b1-b6c5-e0a1da3e577c") format("svg");
}

Comment: Are you using google fonts? or where is your @font-face?

Comment: I think we are not using the Google fonts, I am not able to find the @font-face for UniversLTW01-67BoldCn in my application

Comment: @TimGerhard, why you too much worry about big css selector? Try to focus on problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
Add @font-face {
.auction-bid span, .ending-soon, .auction-ending-soon, .upcoming, .mfxr-logo b, a.divider, .btn-purple, .btn-purple-small-font, .btn-white, .btn-green, .btn-dark-grey, .btn-dark, .btn-green-tko, .btn-green-tko:hover, .signed-up.btn-green-tko, .offer_title h2.thin-purple-title, .rewards-offer p b, .reward-progress-amount, .offer-title, .offer-title-entry-tier, .offer-window, .green-ribbon-text, .acct-points-block span.acct-points, .offer_signup, .offer-item-level, .redeem-now, .redeem-now-internal a, .offer_signup_bundle, .offer-detail-message-block p.offer-message-title, .hero-content-entry-tier-benefits p.hero-title-entry-tier-benefits span, .survey-thank-you, .reward-redemption-tabs li a, .survey-thank-you {
    font-family: "UniversLTW01-67BoldCn",sans-serif;
}
}
```

Comment: `@font-face` needs a `src` element **and** no class specifiers **and** a *single* family name. Proper format is: `@font-face { font-family: nameToUseInCss; src: url(something.woff); }`. Furthermore this is not what the OP needs, it looks like OP has the font but can't use it in IE.